# Macro to Count Rows in One Table and Add that # Rows in Second Table

Tags: vba, count, ms-word, row

I have a word document with a number of tables. 
I'm trying to build a Macro to count the number of rows in Table1, store that number as Variable: [n_rows], then insert [n_rows] into Table7.
I'm working with bookmarks in case users add new tables, but I'm open to the idea of just using ActiveDocument Tables or whatever. 
I'm getting "invalid or unqualified reference" on my .Variables line of my code (see below).
Help!

```
Sub CountRows()
'
'   CountRows
'
'
If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Objectives") = True Then
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Item("Objectives").Select
.Variables("numrows").Value = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count
End If
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="LogFrameSO"
Selection.InsertRowsBelow [NumRows]
End Sub
```

Comment: You're getting an error because you have `.Variables` with no qualifier. I assume you mean `ActiveDocument.Variables`. Fix that and your code will run without an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to be using code like:

.Variables("numrows").Value

1. a Document variable named 'numrows' would have to exist; and
2. with your existing code, you would need to reference it as ActiveDocument.Variables("numrows").Value in both instances.

Try:

```
Sub AddRows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Long, i As Long
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists("Objectives") Then
    r = .Bookmarks("Objectives").Range.Tables(1).Rows.Count
  End If
  If .Bookmarks.Exists("LogFrameSO") Then
    With .Bookmarks("LogFrameSO").Range.Tables(1).Rows
      For i = 1 To r
        .Add
      Next
    End With
  End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is almost perfect thank you so much!
The only strange thing I'm seeing is that it seems to add double the number of rows. 
That wouldn't bother me, except my second action which is to copy text from the objectives table to the Logframe table copies the text twice as well. It seems like however many rows exist in the destination, that's how many times it will copy the text.

Comment: Your original post indicated that you want to add as many rows to the LogFrameSO table as the row count for the Objectives table; not to give both tables the same row count as the Objectives table. Are you sure it's not the latter you're after?

Comment: Originally I wanted it just to add the number of rows. However if Objectives has 2 rows, and LogFrame has 4 rows, the code you gave adds 8 additional rows to Logframe, not 4. So where I should now have a total of 6 rows, I have 10. 
It would be fine to have a few extra rows, except that now my other code just copies the text over and over until it fills all the rows.

Comment: Unless your bookmarks are both in the *same* table, or the Objectives bookmark spans more than one table and the one being processed isn't the wrong one, it's impossible for the code to do as you describe.